nginx working on http but on https giving 502 error
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name pelot.ir; # Replace with your domain name

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name pelot.ir; # Replace with your domain name

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

pelot.ir on port 80 works totally fine but on 443(https) giving 502. how to solve it?

I don't see ssl flag in your listen directive. It should be listen 443 ssl; listen [::]:443 ssl;

Why do you think its nginx causing the 502 rather than the origin host? What do your nginx logs say? What do you the logs from the origin server say? These are the most basic steps in troubleshooting. But  the immediate issue is that you've not specified ssl nor provided a certificate.

@AlexeyTen Yeah my question was stupid. sorry and thanks for your help!

Ok, I know I'm a noob in webserver but all I needed to do was just installing certbot and run it with nginx flag.
The conf was updated automatically.
